# Is there a way to evaluate variable in source map inside the Chrome Developer tools?

Tags: javascript, gwt, google-chrome-devtools

I'm debugging a GWT app using SuperDevMode in Chrome. What it gives me is the access to Java source maps in devtools.

My problem is that when I'm debugging the code I would like to evaluate some of the variables.

My question is - is it possible to evaluate a variable from the source map?

If not - is it possible to navigate from the source map to the compiled javascript code?

Comment: You mean, aside from the variables with Java-like names appearing in the Scope section when you pause? Because that's where the values of your scope variables are shown.

Comment: Yes - because I have some properties that are accessible from setters and getters that I would like to inspect. Also, I don't see there properties of static classes (they may be there, but they are obscured to the point I can't identify).

Comment: I had a similar issue, [this was my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77385529/13762264)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Closest I can get to this is "Store as global variable" (Chrome 75):

[image: chrome debugger]

It will get named something like `temp1` in the console. You can then interact with it like any other variable. If there's a better way I'd love to know about it.