# Is there a way to log source-mapped variables in Chrome logpoints?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome, debugging, webpack

[Logpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/01/devtools)

Related: [Is there a way to evaluate variable in source map inside the Chrome Developer tools?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33149499/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-variable-in-source-map-inside-the-chrome-developer-to)

Like a lot of devs I am writing in a JS language and then using a tool to transpile down to a browser-friendly version of my code.

This seems to break the logpoints in Chrome. For instance, I want to log `segmentParameters`:

[image: segment code]

So I add a logpoint:

[image: add log point]

But it seems like this doesn't work because `segmentParameters` is actually called something else like `_a` or something equally cryptic in the live (local machine, transpiled) code. The code is definitely being hit but the logpoint isn't doing anything. I can debug it and store that local value in a temp variable and get to `segmentParameters` that way (I suspect Chrome is doing a little magic to match up the running code to the transpiled code).

BTW the console won't do this either:

[image: console access doesn't work either]

Are there any tricks to getting logpoints working with transpiled code? Something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: We're you able to figure this one out? In my case, logpoints only works if I don't add any variables.

Comment: if you're in source-mapped code the variable that's available for logging might not have the same name as what's on screen. I think that's what I ran into.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome now has an experimental feature called `Resolve variable names in expressions using source maps` turning this on from dev tools settings allows using variable names as found in the source map in the console.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where I was trying to get the value of an argument for a function that looked like this:

```js
public isSuperPoweredThing (thing: IThing, queryParams: Params): boolean {
    let isPageOneSearch = this.isPageOneSearch(queryParams);
    let isKeywordSearch = this.isKeywordSearch(queryParams);

    return isSearchOnPageOne && isDefaultKeywordSearch && !!thing?.superPower?.superPowerId;
}
```

When I tried to add a breakpoint but it didn't seem to exist under the variable name it was given in code: `thing`. I managed to get the value I wanted using the [arguments keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), specifically:  `arguments[0]`.